# Flutter - Extended floating popup in bottomBarNavigation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to make Extended floating popup in bottomBarNavigation, like in this image

[image: Want this type of design]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with `BottomNavigationBar`:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: 0,
      items: [
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
          label: "Home",
        ),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
          label: "Publish",
        ),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.delete),
          label: "Profile",
        )
      ],
      onTap: (index) {
        if (index == 1) {
          print("Call");
          showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0,
              builder: (builder) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 58 + 32),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('1')),
                      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('2')),
                      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('3')),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              });
        }
      },
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/animated_floating_buttons package to achieve your functionality